# Kentico 7, How to drill into CMS and get the images in an HTML page

Tags: c#, content-management-system, kentico

Hi I'm fairly new to Kentico. I need to access the CMS and get images to my html page. how do i do that, have seen methods like getURL, but dont know which context i use them

Answer (score 1):

If the places where you enter content on the page are rich text, meaning you type in them and a toolbar appears which allows you to format text & do other stuff, then there is an icon that looks like a film strip, click that and you should be able to select an image from the media library.

or 
If there is nowhere to do that, then click on the Design view and add an editable image web part to the page template.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what you mean by HTML page?

Are you using the portal engine to design your page? if so, you can add the image using a static html web part, and just add the url to the file, getting the url depends on where it is stored. is it an Attachment? In a Media Library? In your App Themes?

-UPDATE-
Since you are storing your files in the Media Library, there are a couple ways to display the image on the page.

1. Static HTML - You can go to the page, design tab, add a static html web part, in that webpart add the HTML for the image. Something like   To get the URL, you can go to the media library, and select the image you want, and in the panel at the bottom it should have the URL for the image.
2. Add the Editable Image Web Part to the page, you can then set the default image in the web part properties, and using those dialogs you should be able to select the file from the media library. Additionally, once the web part is on the page, you should be able to switch to the page tab, and select the image you want there.

Comment: Thanks for responding, so i am working on a an old project which uses Kentico CMS. I basically want to add some images stored in the media library of the cms to a webpage which has a design and source page

Comment: I'm confused, who do i link the images in media librarary of CMS with the page content in the server